# Pine script indicator problem (probably code outdated)

Tags: pine-script, indicator, tradingview-api

I am new to Pine script, more R user, so pine script code is quite easy to understand but I've got problem with indicator called "Open Interest:CME e-o-d vs CFTC e-o-w" - the pirple line (contracts sum) does not shows `plot(OiSum>0?OiSum:na, color=purple, title="CME e-o-d\n 9 cntrcts sum", linewidth=3,offset=OffSet)`, maybe because of the contracts data not collecting.

Main problem is that I couldn't find function discription "getCntrct" so that I could understand where it goes and e.t.c.

Any help would be prefect.

```
//@version=3
study("Open Interest:CME e-o-d vs CFTC e-o-w", precision=0,overlay=true, scale=scale.left)
ChkComm = input("", title="override symbol (SI/CL etc)", type=string)


ChkPrelim = input(0, title="Prelim.OI", type=integer)
Prelim=(ChkPrelim>0?ChkPrelim:0)

fxroot =
          ticker == "XAUUSD" ? "GC" :
          ticker == "XAGUSD" ? "SI" :
          "" 
ThisComm = ChkComm == "" ? fxroot == "" ? syminfo.root : fxroot : ChkComm
// root = syminfo.root 
code = ThisComm
getCntrct(fut,num,max) =>
    N=tostring(num)
    C=num<=max?security("QUANDL:CHRIS/CME_"+fut+N+"|7", "D", close,barmerge.gaps_on, barmerge.lookahead_on):0
    Cx=(C?C:0) // not na? OK, else 0
// NUMBER OF CONTRACTS
// CME Vol and Open Interesst page eg. for GOLD:
// https://www.cmegroup.com/markets/metals/precious/gold.volume.html#
// Totals Volume & OI (last line of table) are not  exported 

// CME data is recorded&exported daily by quandl.com to tradingview
// via the che CHRIS/CME datasets
// https://www.quandl.com/data/CHRIS
// Eg. Nat GAs cntract n. 20, field n. 7(OI)
// https://www.quandl.com/data/CHRIS/CME_NG20 (@quandl.com)
// https://www.tradingview.com/e/?symbol=QUANDL:CHRIS/CME_NG20|7 (@tradingview)

// This script tries to sum all the fut cntrcts' Vol&OI to obtain a fair total
//
// Number of cntrcts per commodity differ.
// eg E-mini (ES) has 4 contracts, Gold(GC) 16 cntrcts, NatGas(NG) has 43, WTI(CL) has 38 etc
// see https://s3.amazonaws.com/quandl-production-static/Ticker+CSV%27s/Futures/continuous.csv

getNc(code)=>
// set the N.of outstanding contracts per future code 
    c=16               //default 16
    c:=code=="AD"?2:c  //Australian Dollar  
    c:=code=="BB"?5:c  //Brent Crude Oil  HMUZ
    c:=code=="BP"?2:c  //British Pound  FGHJKMNQUVXZ
    c:=code=="C"?11:c  //Corn  HMUZ
    c:=code=="CD"?4:c  //Canadian Dollar  HKNUZ
    c:=code=="CL"?38:c  //WTI Crude Oil  HMUZ 
    c:=code=="CNH"?2:c  //Standard-Size USD/Offshore RMB (CNH)  FGHJKMNQUVXZ
    c:=code=="EC"?2:c  //Euro FX  FGHJKMNQUVXZ
    c:=code=="ES"?4:c  //E-mini S&P 500 Index  HMUZ
    c:=code=="FC"?7:c  //Feeder Cattle  HMUZ
    c:=code=="FV"?2:c  //5 Year Treasury Note  FHJKQUVX
    c:=code=="GC"?16:c  //Gold  HMUZ
    c:=code=="HG"?11:c  //Copper  GHJKMQVZ
    c:=code=="HO"?17:c  //Heating Oil  FGHJKMNQUVXZ
    c:=code=="IBV"?2:c  //Ibovespa Index  FGHJKMNQUVXZ
    c:=code=="JY"?2:c  //Japanese Yen  GJMQVZ
    c:=code=="LB"?2:c  //Lumber  HMUZ
    c:=code=="LC"?7:c  //Live Cattle  FHKNUX
    c:=code=="LN"?10:c  //Lean Hogs  GJMQVZ
    c:=code=="ND"?2:c  //NASDAQ 100  GJKMNQVZ
    c:=code=="NE"?2:c  //New Zealand Dollar  HMUZ
    c:=code=="NF"?4:c  //Nonfat Dry Milk  HMUZ
// as max securities for pine scripts is 40, NG has too many! lowered to 39
//  c:=code=="NG"?43:c  //Natural Gas  FGHJKMNQUVXZ
    c:=code=="NG"?39:c  //Natural Gas  FGHJKMNQUVXZ
    c:=code=="NQ"?2:c  //E-mini NASDAQ 100 Index  HMUZ
    c:=code=="O"?3:c  //Oats  HMUZ
    c:=code=="PA"?2:c  //Palladium  HKNUZ
    c:=code=="PL"?3:c  //Platinum  HJKMUZ
    c:=code=="QL"?2:c  //Coal  FHJKNV
    c:=code=="RB"?10:c  //Gasoline  FGHJKMNQUVXZ
    c:=code=="RBB"?10:c  //RBOB Gasoline Brent Crack Spread  FGHJKMNQUVXZ
    c:=code=="RP"?2:c  //Euro/British Pound  FGHJKMNQUVXZ
    c:=code=="RR"?3:c  //Rough Rice  HMUZ
    c:=code=="RU"?7:c  //Russian Ruble  FHKNUX
    c:=code=="RY"?2:c  //Euro/Japanese Yen  FGHJKMNQUVXZ
    c:=code=="S"?10:c  //Soybeans  HMUZ
    c:=code=="SF"?2:c  //Swiss Franc  FHKNQUX
    c:=code=="SI"?12:c  //Silver  HMUZ
    c:=code=="SM"?11:c  //Soybean Meal  FHJKNUZ
    c:=code=="SP"?3:c  //Full-Size S&P 500 Index  FHKNQUVZ
    c:=code=="TRY"?2:c  //Turkish Lira  HMUZ
    c:=code=="TU"?2:c  //2 Year Treasury Note  HMUZ
    c:=code=="TY"?2:c  //10 Year Treasury Note  HMUZ
    c:=code=="UL"?2:c  //Ultra Treasury Bond  HMUZ
    c:=code=="US"?2:c  //30-Year Treasury Bond  HMUZ
    c:=code=="W"?7:c  //Wheat  HMUZ
    c:=code=="XAF"?2:c  //E-mini Financial Sector  HKNUZ
    c:=code=="XAK"?2:c  //E-mini Technology Sector  HM
    c:=code=="XAP"?2:c  //E-mini Consumer Staples Sector  HM
    c:=code=="XAU"?2:c  //E-mini Utilities Sector  HM
    c:=code=="XAY"?2:c  //E-mini Consumer Discretionary Sector  HM

// unfortunately, "securuty" can't be called inside a for loop,so:

C1=getCntrct(code,1,getNc(code))
C2=getCntrct(code,2,getNc(code))
C3=getCntrct(code,3,getNc(code))
C4=getCntrct(code,4,getNc(code))
C5=getCntrct(code,5,getNc(code))
C6=getCntrct(code,6,getNc(code))
C7=getCntrct(code,7,getNc(code))
C8=getCntrct(code,8,getNc(code))
C9=getCntrct(code,9,getNc(code))
C10=getCntrct(code,10,getNc(code))
C11=getCntrct(code,11,getNc(code))
C12=getCntrct(code,12,getNc(code))
C13=getCntrct(code,13,getNc(code))
C14=getCntrct(code,14,getNc(code))
C15=getCntrct(code,15,getNc(code))
C16=getCntrct(code,16,getNc(code))
C17=getCntrct(code,17,getNc(code))
C18=getCntrct(code,18,getNc(code))
C19=getCntrct(code,19,getNc(code))
C20=getCntrct(code,20,getNc(code))
C21=getCntrct(code,21,getNc(code))
C22=getCntrct(code,22,getNc(code))
C23=getCntrct(code,23,getNc(code))
C24=getCntrct(code,24,getNc(code))
C25=getCntrct(code,25,getNc(code))
C26=getCntrct(code,26,getNc(code))
C27=getCntrct(code,27,getNc(code))
C28=getCntrct(code,28,getNc(code))
C29=getCntrct(code,29,getNc(code))
C30=getCntrct(code,30,getNc(code))
C31=getCntrct(code,31,getNc(code))
C32=getCntrct(code,32,getNc(code))
C33=getCntrct(code,33,getNc(code))
C34=getCntrct(code,34,getNc(code))
C35=getCntrct(code,35,getNc(code))
C36=getCntrct(code,36,getNc(code))
C37=getCntrct(code,37,getNc(code))
C38=getCntrct(code,38,getNc(code))
C39=getCntrct(code,39,getNc(code))
// max securities for scripts is 40!

OiSum=C1+C2+C3+C4+C5+C6+C7+C8+C9+C10+C11+C12+C13+C14+C15+C16+C17+C18+C19+C20+C21+C22+C23+C24+C25+C26+C27
     +C28+C29+C30+C31+C32+C33+C34+C35+C36+C37+C38+C39
///////// CFTC COT Open Interest
CftcOI = security("QUANDL:CFTC/"+code+"_F_ALL|0", "W", close, barmerge.gaps_off, barmerge.lookahead_on)
plot(CftcOI, color=orange, title="CFTC COT OI", linewidth=3)
// lastBar function
lastBar=(barstate.islast and close ?  barstate.islast : na)
lB=lastBar
//day of week function
isMon() => dayofweek(time('D')) == monday and close ? 1 : 0
isTue() => dayofweek(time('D')) == tuesday and close ? 1 : 0
isWed() => dayofweek(time('D')) == wednesday and close ? 1 : 0
isThu() => dayofweek(time('D')) == thursday and close ? 1 : 0
isFri() => dayofweek(time('D')) == friday and close ? 1 : 0
NowIsSat() => dayofweek(timenow) == 7 ? 1: 0
NowIsSun() => dayofweek(timenow) == 1 ? 1: 0
//default label params to shorten command lines
s=shape.labeldown
l=location.absolute
tc=black
sz=size.tiny
o=+1
e=true
tr=70
// if lastblock is on Fri but we are on Sat or Sun...

//OffSetPrelim=(Prelim>0?OffSet+1:OffSet)
OffSet=-1
//OffSetPrelim=OffSet
OffSetPrelim=(NowIsSat() or NowIsSun()? 0:OffSet)
// Sum of next 20 contracts OI
plot(OiSum>0?OiSum:na, color=purple, title="CME e-o-d\n 9 cntrcts sum", linewidth=3,offset=OffSet)
// If a Prelim has been entered
plot(lB and Prelim > 0?Prelim:na, offset=OffSetPrelim,  style=cross, color=black,title="Preliminary OI", linewidth=4)
// labels
plotshape(lB and Prelim > 0?Prelim:na, show_last=1,color=black,text="Preliminary OI",editable=e,location=l,style=shape.cross,textcolor=black,size=size.small,offset=OffSetPrelim,transp=30)
plotshape(lB and CftcOI?CftcOI:na, color=purple, text ="CME e-o-d OI ",editable=e,style=shape.labelup,location=l,textcolor=tc,size=s,offset=+1,transp=tr)
plotshape(lB and CftcOI?CftcOI:na, color=orange, text="CFTC Weekly OI",editable=true,style=s,location=l,textcolor=tc,size=s,offset=+1,transp=tr)
```

Discription on Trading View - https://www.tradingview.com/script/7EvGzM0a-Open-Interest-CME-e-o-d-vs-CFTC-e-o-w/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `getCntrct()` function is used to construct the ticker/quandl code and retrieve via security call the OI values.

The script expects you to specify the prefix for the contracts manually except for gold and silver. For those if you change the chart ticker to XAUUSD or XAGUSD you'll see the script plot the OI values.

For others, eg for the Australian Dollar OI values, you'd have to change the "override symbol (SI/CL etc)" setting to "AD" (input variable `ChkComm`)

For the Australian Dollar this will construct the quandl code for the security call :

`QUANDL:CHRIS/CME_AD1|7`

`QUANDL:CHRIS/CME_AD2|7`

etc

(you can also view these directly by using it as a ticker id on the chart itself)

The "pipe" symbol `|` is used to reference which field in the table of values, with 7 being the OI value. You can view the corresponding table for AD1 here :

https://www.quandl.com/data/CHRIS/CME_AD1